# MS Outlook 2010 Warning About External Programs

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I keep getting this message:

[image]

...and for the life of me I cannot figure out what program might be trying to access my email address information - any ideas for getting rid of this message or tracking down the offending program?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software?

run a complete scan.

Comment: If you have any macros running they could potentially cause this depending on what they are doing.

Comment: Do you have a smartphone, or similar device, particularly in a cradle? Is there anything in your application event log?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is a COM add-in of a product you installed, which can be disabled through Outlook Security Settings template.

Try to run Outlook in safe mode and see if it still happens - to do so type in the Run window `outlook.exe /safe` (or press `CTRL` button on your keyboard when clicking the Outlook shortcut)

To disable COM add-ins go to **File | Options | Add-ins** and click on the **Go...** button

[image]

Here, try to disable these add-ins one by one and see who is the one that is actually causing the problem.

[image]

Comment: +1 Related: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/i-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-e-mail-address-information-or-sending-e-mail-on-my-behalf-HA001229943.aspx This is for 2007, but 2010 is similar.